# unable to install Weblogic server 12C, the jar file is not even opening

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

**unable to install Weblogic server 12C, the jar file is not even opening. Tried instaling from command prompt as Admin , ended up with error unable to access jar file. I have java 7 installed. Please help**

**info copied from log file..**

```
2016-12-22 10:30:19,591 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Extracting the installer . . .
2016-12-22 10:30:23,626 INFO  [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Finished self extraction to C:\Users\Anand\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl3227252922117189327.tmp.
2016-12-22 10:30:23,839 WARNING [1] com.oracle.cie.common.jni.WinRegistryHelper - Create Key Failed: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Oracle
2016-12-22 10:30:23,839 SEVERE [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.PlatformHelper - createRegistry to add a value failed
2016-12-22 10:30:23,839 SEVERE [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher - Unable to access or modify the system registry.  Select Run as Administrator when opening the Command Prompt and try again.
2016-12-22 10:30:23,872 SEVERE [1] com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.Launcher - Unable to access or modify the system registry.  Select Run as Administrator when opening the Command Prompt and try again.
```

Comment: have you tried creating the registry key yourself to see if you really have admin privileges? what's your OS?

Comment: Yes, Turkis. I do have Admin privileges..OS is Windows 7,64 Bit

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the command prompt in administrator mode, then try this
2. java -d64 -jar fmw_12.2.1.2.0_wls.jar

Refer this link for further details:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/doc.1211/e24492/guimode.htm#WLSIG198

Comment: I had to run the java command from within a JDK version which is newer or the same as the supported JDK version of the WebLogic server. For instance, I had to run Oracle Fusion Middleware 12.0 using JDK 8.

Answer (score 2):

Even I have got the same problem and its resolved, 
Make sure you have done the below steps,

```
1.install java, a  compatible version from the internet, and set JAVA_HOME and path variables.
JAVA_HOME: JDK home directory path
path: jdk>bin directory path

2.execute the below line in command prompt which is opened with a privilege [Run As An Administrator].
  java -jar D:\softwares\servers\fmw_12.1.3.0.0_wls.jar

3.it will take a moment to extract all the files and installation begins.
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but, if someone new drops by, this may be usefull.
This problem is caused by a lack of permissions with the current OS Windows user.
You need to right click on top of the CMD icon and choose Run as Administrator.
Inside the DOS command line window go to your JDK source folder.
Then type the following command line:
java.exe -jar "path to the weblogic jar file".
Several checks will be madde and the weblogic installation window will appear.

Answer (score 0):

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351\bin\java" -jar weblogic.jar
the above command works fine. you need to have the latest version of jdk installed in your machine.
weblogic.jar is the jar filename which has been downloaded.